# VSCode Xdebug and DBGp proxy

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm trying to debug PHP application hosted on SFTP in Visual Studio Code.
Actually I'm using "Php Debug" plugin with this configuration:

```
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9001,
        "serverSourceRoot": "/var/www/httpdocs/project",
        "localSourceRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    },
```

Obviously it does not work because I have no set DBGp proxy or something like that.

Because it is for work my company suggest me to use PhpStorm and linked me to this:

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Multi-user+debugging+in+PhpStorm+with+Xdebug+and+DBGp+proxy

How to do it with VSCode?

Comment: Question is: Do you actually need DBGp proxy here? Maybe simple SSH tunnel will do the job as well?

Comment: I am working for a Company and I cannot modify the php.ini on the server. It is configured with remote_host=$proxy_ip so I think cannot use it as non-proxy.

Comment: Fair enough. As long as you know it's a DBGp proxy, of course. As for actual question -- I'm not VSC user so cannot help here. But .. you can use PhpStorm :) for debug if unable to find VSC solution -- even if it will be for this (short) debug session.

Answer (score 4):

Check this answer !

1. DBGp proxy client
   download from http://code.activestate.com/komodo/remotedebugging/
   , i use Komodo-PythonRemoteDebugging-11.0.2-90813-linux-x86_64.tar

   My bash

```
#!/bin/bash

export PYTHONPATH=./pythonlib
python -c "import dbgp.client; print 'import lib ok'"

./pydbgpproxy -d 0.0.0.0:9999 -i 0.0.0.0:9001
```

and run

```
import lib ok
INFO: dbgp.proxy: starting proxy listeners.  appid: 20018
INFO: dbgp.proxy:     dbgp listener on 0.0.0.0:9999
INFO: dbgp.proxy:     IDE listener on  0.0.0.0:9001
```

The php xdebug.ini

```
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 10.0.1.88 # DBGp ip 
xdebug.remote_port = 9999 # DBGp port
```

2. ssh tunnel with port

   .ssh/config

```
# ...
RemoteForward 20000 localhost:20000 # vscode php-debug config
LocalForward 9001 localhost:9001 # DBGp port
# ...
```

and connect with ssh

3. vscode launch.json

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name"        : "vscphpdebug",
            "type"        : "php",
            "request"     : "launch",
            "port"        : 20000,
            "stopOnEntry" : false,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/server/php": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
        }
    ]
```

and start debug in vscode

4. telnet the DBGp port and register key use: proxyinit -p 20000 -k vscdebug -m 1

```
$telnet 127.0.0.1 9001
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
proxyinit -p 20000 -k vscdebug -m 1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxyinit success="1" idekey="vscdebug" address="0.0.0.0" port="9999"/>Connection closed by foreign host.
```

and stop DBGp use this: proxystop -k vscdebug

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 9001
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
proxystop -k vscdebug
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxystop success="1" idekey="vscdebug"/>Connection closed by foreign host.
```

5. Start debug on VSCode(PHP Debug
   felixfbecker.php-debug)

Happy Debug !

Comment: Don't know why this answer would be downvoted when it's actually the correct answer as of 2/23/2020.  As shown by the Github issue: https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug/issues/107 that after more than 3 years this feature is still not implemented in Felix Becker's PHP debug extension.  If you have to get multi-user debugging working through a dbgp proxy under vscode then setting up the ssh tunnels is the only way.  I would change the telnet command to be simply: echo "proxyinit -p 20000 -k vscdebug -m 1" | nc dbgphost 9001